# Is there a "non-hacky" way to update PyQt5 Apps (Python)?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, updates

**Intro**
So I've completed an application with PyQt5 using Python and I'd like to start distributing. However, the app will need to receive new data & update accordingly.

**Quick Background:**
The intention currently is to have every employee download this app on their work computer. 
I want to minimize employee involvement in code/text files.

**Small Example:**
I have names of employees in a file, say, file.txt.
In the code itself, I read from this file and add the names to a QComboBox Widget.

Say I have a new employee, Employee A.

Ideally, I could alert each app user that there's a new update out and have them download the update.

When downloaded, Employee A will be added to file.txt.

**My Current Solution**

1. when loading up the app, go to a website and scrape a version
   number from the website
2. if the website version number =/= the app's current version number,
   alert the user they need to download an update from the website
3. design a script that updates any information in the data files (This is what they'd be downloading. The script would have, for example, new employee names and would add the new names to the text data files.)

Is there possibly some library I'm missing that makes this easier? Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: There is no need to 'scrape', and especially from a controlled source in 2020 :| There are numerous existing package managers - there might be some that provide a suitable method to integrate (or some existing Python code/example that does).

Comment: Search for ["self updating python application"](https://www.google.com/search?q=self+updating+python+application) - seems to already be a solved problem in general for Python. The devil is [just] the details..